# Is it possible to set an Oracle CLOB column value to NULL from ADO

Tags: c++, oracle, oracle11g, ado, clob

I have a C++ application that uses ADO to connect to an Oracle 11 database. I have a requirement to set a CLOB column value to NULL. I am getting a **_FieldPtr** and setting its **Value** to an uninitialized **_variant_t** OR an empty **_bstr_t** OR a _variant_t with its type set to **VT_NULL** but it always sets the CLOB value to an EMPTY_CLOB instead of NULL.

Is there any known limitation? Any workarounds that can be used?